# Automator.app "Watch me do" loop gets slower and slower

Tags: macos, automator, automation, memory-leak

I have been using Automator to run "Watch Me Do" loop to click places repeatedly for tedious tasks. The loop works perfectly, but the longer the loop runs for over time the mouse movement and clicks get slower and slower.

Relaunching Automator does not reset the slowdown. The only "fix" I have found is to reboot my MacOS.

Anyone here know how to fix this?

Comment: Without seeing the **Automator** _workflow_ it's hard to say other then adjusting timings. However, I'd look at the possibility of converting the **Watch Me Do** _workflow_ to **AppleScript** _code_, cleaning it up to be as written _code_ would be, and then use the **AppleScript** _code_ as appropriate to the situation. It will probably work better than the **Watch Me Do** _workflow_ ever did.

Comment: "converting the Watch Me Do workflow to AppleScript code" I'm newbie with Automator, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the Log grows and grows with each loop.